# BDD works local but doesn't work in GitLab Pipeline with Alpine Linux

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, gitlab-ci, pipeline, alpine-linux

My scenario scheme with negative tests are failing, but when I run locally they pass.
According to my BDD the system message for invalid access is Portuguese but I receive it in English.  expected: "Login/Senha incorreto"
got: "Access Denied: Invalid credentials."

```
My code in file: .gitlab-cy.yml
before_script: 
 - chmod +x alpine.sh
 - ./alpine.sh
 - gem install bundler --no-document

image: ruby:alpine

test:
  stage: test
  script:
  - bundle install
  - bundle exec cucumber
  
code file alpine.sh
echo "http://dl-4.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
echo "http://dl-4.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories 

apk update && \
    apk add build-base \
    libxml2-dev \
    libxslt-dev \
    curl unzip libexif udev chromium chromium-chromedriver wait4ports xvfb xorg-server dbus ttf-freefont mesa-dri-swrast \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

message error pipeline gitlab
Scenario: Logar com credenciais invalidas
The results is: ✗
----------------------------------------------
      |   tester    |    1234     |  Login/Senha incorreto |  
  
  ----------------------------------------------, Reason:, 
  expected: "Login/Senha incorreto"
       got: "Access Denied: Invalid credentials."
  
  (compared using eql?)
  , ----------------------------------------------
      
      expected: "Login/Senha incorreto"
           got: "Access Denied: Invalid credentials."
      
      (compared using eql?)
       (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
      ./features/step_definitions/login.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
      ./features/step_definitions/login.rb:20:in `nil'
      features/specs/login.feature:18:14:in `ele visualiza a mensagem de alerta "Login/Senha incorreto"'
true
Results:
```

Comment: Sounds like the application under test has localized error messages. These may be derived from the language of the OS it runs on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try forcing the OS language with:

```
export LANG=C
```

or

```
export LC_ALL=C
```

or `en_US.UTF-8` or similar.

So in your use case:

```
before_script: 
 - chmod +x alpine.sh
 - export LC_ALL=C
 - ./alpine.sh
 - gem install bundler --no-document
```

or

```
test:
  stage: test
  script:
  - export LC_ALL=C
  - bundle install
  - bundle exec cucumber
```

I'm not able to understand which block ends with error by looking at the output you provided.

Comment: Sorry David but in which file and in which position do I implement this, alpine.sh?

Comment: my alpine.sh                                                                                                                      
 apk update && \
    apk add build-base \
    libxml2-dev \
    libxslt-dev \
    curl unzip libexif udev chromium chromium-chromedriver wait4ports xvfb xorg-server dbus ttf-freefont mesa-dri-swrast \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

Comment: You can add the export in the first line of the script `alpine.sh` or execute the export  before running this script in `before_script`.

Comment: I really appreciate your help but it hasn't worked yet, I honestly don't know what to do...

Comment: Hope the last modification to my answear will help.

Comment: David, i I'll try!!!

Comment: My problem is that my app messages are in Portuguese, but the docker is in English! .

Comment: expected: "Login/Senha incorreto" - Portuguese 
       got: "Access Denied: Invalid credentials."  the same message the docker translates to english, so my test fails

Comment: My brother, You helped me a lot...  See de commands:  before_script: 
  - chmod +x alpine.sh
  - ./alpine.sh
  - gem install bundler --no-document
  - apk add --no-cache tzdata
  - cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Sao_Paulo /etc/localtime
  - echo "America/Sao_Paulo" >  /etc/timezone
image: ruby:alpine
variables:
  TZ: America/Sao_Paulo
  LANG: pt_BR.UTF-8
  LANGUAGE: pt_BR.UTF-8
  LC_ALL: pt_BR.UTF-8
test:
  stage: test
  script:
  - bundle install
  - bundle exec cucumber

Comment: I took your command and attached it to another command from a friend... You are my Idol too...lol